# Control I characters in my text file

Tags: vim, character-encoding

I have no idea how did I suddenly get ^I characters in my source code file.

Everywhere I had a space ( but only in the beginning of the line ) , it shows up as ^I. This is making my code very very unreadable.

I am using vim as an editor.

Can anyone tell me what could have led this to happen and how can I replace them again with an invisible blank space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^I` (Ctrl-I) is a representation of the tab character (9 in ASCII). Usually,
Vim displays tab characters by the number of space characters as specified in
the `tabstop` option. However, setting the `list` option, displays various unprintable characters and one of its effects is to display Tab as a control character. To check if this option is set, you can run `:set list?` (and `set listchars?`).

To replace the tab characters with spaces, run `:%s/^I/ /g`. The `^I` control character can be obtained by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Indeed set list was in my .vimrc. No need to find and replace. Simply removing the entry from the file helped.

Answer (score 0):

One can replace them with an regex in VIM.

```
:%s/[\x09]/ /gc
```

check if there is an entry

```
set list
```

in the .vimrc file. Hint taken from the accepted answer.